# Showing multiple user controls in table

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a table from code behind file.

```
MyControl control1 = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
control1.ID = "ctl1";
MyControl control2 = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
control2.ID = "ctl2";
MyControl control3 = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
control3.ID = "ctl3";
MyControl control4 = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
control4.ID = "ctl4";

Table table = new Table();

TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
TableRow row1 = new TableRow();

cell1.Controls.Add(control1);
row1.Cells.Add(cell1);
cell2.Controls.Add(control2);
row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
cell3.Controls.Add(control3);
row1.Cells.Add(cell3);
cell4.Controls.Add(control4);
row1.Cells.Add(cell4);

table.Rows.Add(row1);
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(table);
```

But I see only first control gets loaded, others not. Anything missing?

Comment: No. nothing missing. Show the code for your control, maybe it is overlapping

Comment: <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="220px" style="position:fixed" >
    <tr>
        <td style="width:220px;height:220px">
            <div id="Gauge1" class="gauge">
            </div>
            <a></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> gauge is created with script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controls are there all right.
Your CSS position fixed is causing them to overlap.

I created a [jsfiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/4MtZB/) what is happening.

You can only see the gauge that in the last cell.

It can be fixed by removing the `position: fixed`

See this jsfiddle [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/GPv32/).